# Skip bad EOL in Python

Tags: python, pipe, eol

I'm reading from CAT pipe in Linux, using `subprocess`:

```
stdout=subprocess.PIPE
```

so some line has BAD EOL, it's huge file and I want to skip such lines and go for the next one. how I can do this in Python?

PS: I always get:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

and seems some socket stopped while writing to that file,because I see really huge spaces in the end of that file. Don't want to fix it, want to skip it

here is my code :

```
import sys,os
import subprocess
import traceback
import re
import ast




try :
        cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "dfs", "-cat", "PATH TO FILE"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for data in cat.stdout:
                data = re.sub(' +',' ',data)
                msg= ast.literal_eval(data)
                if  msg['some_string'] == 'some_string' :
                        print msg['status']
                else :
                        continue
except :
        print traceback.format_exc()
        pass
exit()
```

so the output before the programs exits :
many empty spaces and  ...

```
                                                        ^
```

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You have a syntax error in your *Python code*, not in the cat pipe.

Comment: Please show your related code. Looks like the error comes from there.

Comment: print out `data` before the `literal_eval`, that might give us a fighting chance.

Comment: the thing is even on the system file , if you tried cat that file, same issue happens, I know that the file itself is the problem, but is there anyway I set manually EOL and move to the next line and continue processing, knowing that I'm sure that there is data after that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
import sys,os
import subprocess
import traceback
import re
import ast




try :
        cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "dfs", "-cat", "PATH TO FILE"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for data in cat.stdout:
                data = re.sub(' +',' ',data)
                try:
                    msg= ast.literal_eval(data)
                    if  msg['some_string'] == 'some_string' :
                        print msg['status']
                    else :
                        continue
                except SyntaxError:
                    continue #skip this line

except :
        print traceback.format_exc()
        pass
exit()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

to skip errors you can just code smth like:

```
try:
    your code
except {Your error}:
    pass
```

or

```
try:
    your code
except:
    pass
```

for all errors

you could also use smth like:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    {code}
except Exception:
    _type, _value, _trace = sys.exc_info()
    print "Type:\n\t{0}\nException:\n\t\t{1}\nTraceback:\n\t{2}".format(
          _type, _value, traceback.format_tb(_trace))
```

Comment: Not if there is a syntax error in the same file, you cannot. And even if this *was* a EOL problem with the subprocess, that doesn't mean you can just ignore it and blithely continue reading from the pipe.

Comment: This won't skip anything, and the error is in the Python file. This will just abort the process.

Comment: Note that you **rarely** want to use a blanket `except:` statement. If you want to catch all exceptions, use `except Exception:` instead and not catch `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions.

Comment: To be fair, it looks like this (under its `except SyntaxError:` variation) would have been the right approach.  The exception isn't caused by a `SyntaxError` in the Python file, it's being raised by `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: I wrote the easiest way to suppress raised exceptions. It was kinda obvious, that the problem was not in the python syntax. sometimes you just need the code to work, even when the errors raised. `pass` in `except` block is the best temporary way

Comment: Ah, i see now. It's from the `literal_eval`.

Comment: yes pass is not enough here, because program will exit anyway

Comment: @A.Elnaggar it depends on your purpose. I'm used to work with huge amount of data, and when something goes bad, I just log the error in specified format and keep processing. Then I just parse the log and fix errors.

Comment: @oleg.foreigner yes I want to do the same, but pass won't allow me to continue.. I want to skip this and move forward

Comment: @A.Elnaggar this way works great for me. just log or print what you need... I think, you problem is in global `try`. Try to use it in a loop, try to catch errors for every `data` processing in `cat.stdout`

Comment: @oleg.foreigner good hint, still trying to add maually EOL to those courrpted lines